# Is it possible to sort numbers in linear time and constant extra space?

Tags: sorting, space-complexity, linear-complexity

The programming language is C++, and the elements of the input `vector` are of type `int` and able to take all valid `int` values. So it’s not possible to store extra information in the input `vector`. Now, is it possible to sort the `vector` in linear time and constant extra space? Simple solutions are preferred.

And to avoid ridiculous constant factors, the constant factor in linear time is at most 100.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a programming competition question, so the questioner is just trying to cheat.

Comment: When you ask a question based on a resource you have seen elsewhere, please link to the original resource and include the title or other citation for it.  You mentioned that this is based on https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-iii/description/ -- please include that motivation in the question.  This avoids wasting answerers' time and helps others in the future who might have a similar question about the same exercise.

Answer (score 2):

If you require a comparison-based sorting algorithm akin to quicksort and merge sort, the answer is "No." Simply put, it can be proven that sorting an array of $n$ elements using a comparison-based method in that respect would require, at least, a complexity of $O(n\times log(n))$. Alternatively, [Kelly Bundy](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/165624/157952)'s solution works fine and does run in linear time, as requested. However, I would not wager too much in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Of course it’s not comparison-based.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: This was posted before their edit.)

Yes. Move all elements with value $-2^{31}$ to the front, order of the remaining elements doesn't matter. Easy in linear time. Then move all remaining elements with value $-2^{31}+1$ to the front (but after the $-2^{31}$ elements). Then do the same with $-2^{31}+2$, ..., $2^{31}-1$. Total time for $n$ elements is  $O(2^{32}n) = O(n)$.

Comment: This is not linear time. This is wasting time.

Comment: @ZiruiWang It's both.

Comment: Question edited. Please note the extra condition.

Comment: @ZiruiWang I saw. Not friendly trying to invalidate someone's work. (Not that you succeed in that, as I can simply count the billions of steps, so my conclusion becomes like O(4n)=O(n), i.e., my constant factor is only 4 then, which is less than 100.)

Comment: I’m not invalidating your work. I think you did not get the spirit of my question. I could add that you can only perform $10^7$ operations for $n\le10^5$; this is a LeetCode programming question (260 Single Number III: https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-iii/). Sadly I didn’t communicate clearly enough to describe what the question wants. There are other similar questions, which if my question was answered positively, would be easily tackled.

Comment: @ZiruiWang *"this is a LeetCode programming question (260 Single Number III: leetcode.com/problems/single-number-iii)"* - Not really. That LeetCode question is far simpler, sorting is wasteful for that.

Comment: I just voted to close. Rudeness is not a reason to close, but cheating on leetcode questions is.

Comment: @gnasher729 What's the problem with this "cheating", and why is it a reason to close?

Comment: @KellyBundy I think this site is not welcome for questions that have applications in online programming tasks. But this question was on my mind when I saw so many questions that can be directly benefited from its answer. As Kelly said, it’s wasteful to solve this problem, but that also means it’s a powerful question with diverse applications. I’m not “cheating” on one problem, but “cheating” on a bunch of problems or a meta-problem. Does that justify my asking?

Comment: @ZiruiWang the answer to the leetcode question is to use hashmaps, interviewers would not accept sorting

Comment: @KennethKho It's absolutely **not** to use hashmaps.

Comment: @KellyBundy what do you suggest? did i miss something trivial?

Comment: @KennethKho Yes, you missed the requirement *"uses only constant extra space"*. No, I wouldn't call it trivial.